# Why it doesn't save input data to state variable inside <Collapse> tag in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a code to implement a vertical Collapse by using react material UI. But it won't set the Input and TextField values into the state variables. Please help me to find what i did wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Here is the function that is used to handle input changes

```
handleOnChange = async (event) => {
    const field = event.target.name;

    if (field === "Announcement") {
        if (this.isMount) {
            await this.setState({
                announcement: event.target.value,
                isFormDirty: true,
            });
        }
    }
    if (field === "Title") {
        if (this.isMount) {
            await this.setState({
                title: event.target.value,
                isFormDirty: true,
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Part of my `render()` function

```
<form>
        <div>
            <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClickAnnouncement}>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar>
                         <NotificationImportant/>
                    </Avatar>
               </ListItemAvatar>
               <ListItemText primary="Announcements"/>
               {this.state.ListAnnouncementOpen === true ? <ExpandMore/> : <ExpandLess/>}
            </ListItem>

          <Collapse in={this.state.ListAnnouncementOpen} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <div className="row" className = "ml-3" >
                <label htmlFor="" className="mandatory">
                    Title :
                </label>
                <Input
                    placeholder="Title"
                    value={this.state.title}
                    name="Title"
                    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                    required={true}
                />
            </div>

            <div className="row ml-3">
                <TextField
                    id="standard-multiline-flexible"
                    label="Type new Announcement here"
                    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                    className="course-detail-section"
                    name="Announcement"
                    required={true}
                    value={this.state.announcement}
                />

                <Avatar onClick={this.addAnnouncement}>
                    <AddIcon/>
                </Avatar>
            </div>
        </Collapse>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you set `this.isMount` and why do you have as conditional here on your handleChange? Fwiw, you don't need to set you handle change as async await

Comment: Thank You so much. That was exactly what i did wrong. i removed the condition and async. Now it's working perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome